# Why don't scala collections have any human-readable methods like .append, .push, etc

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Scala collections have a bunch of readable and almost readable operators like `:+` and `+:`, but why aren't there any human readable synonyms like `append`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All **mutable** collections in Scala have the [BufferLike trait](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/BufferLike.html) and it defines an **append** method.

**Immutable** collections **do not have** the BufferLike trait and hence only define the other methods that do not change the collection in place but generate a new one.

Comment: Yeah, but why? I can live with a Seq that returns a new Seq after `append`. Why not add such aliases, at least for easier java interoperability.

Comment: Semantics, append in Java is used for various different buffer classes, like StringBuffer and StringBuilder, when you use append you expect it to add to the current object, not create a new object. By defining an append method that creates a new object you break this expectation, which isn't nice at all.

Answer (score 4):

Symbolic method names allow the combination with the assignment operation `=`.

For instance, if you have a method `++` which creates a new collection, you can automatically use `++=` to assign the new collection to some variable:

```
var array = Array(1,2,3)
array ++= Array(4,5,6)
// array is now Array(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

This is not possible without symbolic method names.

Answer (score 3):

In fact they often some human-readable synonyms:

- `foldLeft` is equivalent to `/:`
- `foldRight` is equivalent to `:\`

The remaining ones are addition operators, which are quite human readable as they are:

- `++` is equivalent to java `addAll`
- `:+` is append
- `+:` is prepend

The position of the semi-colon indicates the receiver instance.

Finally, some weird operators are legacies of other functional programming languages. Such as list construction (SML) or actor messaging (erlang).

Comment: I'm not sure that `:+` and `append` are the same. I think the former (from `SeqLike`) creates a new collection while the latter (from `BufferLike`) modifies the buffer in place.

Comment: Yes, they have different semantic in Scala, but it still an "append" operation.

Answer (score 2):

Is it any different than any other language?

Let's take Java. What's the human readable version of `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` on `int`? Or, let's take `String`: what's the human readable version of `+`? Note that `concat` is not the same thing -- it doesn't accept non-`String` parameters.

Perhaps you are bothered by it because in Java -- unlike, say, C++ -- either things use exclusively non-alphabetic operators, or alphabetic operators -- with the exception of `String`'s `+`.

Answer (score 0):

The Scala standard library does not set out to be Java friendly. Instead, adapters are provided to convert between Java and Scala collections.

Attempting to provide a Java friendly API would not only constrain the choice of identifiers (or mandate that aliases should be provided), but also limit the way that generics and function types were used. Substantially more testing would be required to validate the design.

On the same topic, I remember some debate as to whether the 2.8 collections should implement `java.util.Iterable`.

http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/How-to-set-the-scale-for-scala-BigDecimal-s-method-td1948885.html

http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2177